# icarus verilog: Unable to bind variable

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

I am trying to pass a string as parameter to a module and getting this error:

> Unable to bind variable

```
module dut #(parameter string CONFIG_FILE) 
(
input logic clk
);
endmodule

module main;
localparam string CONFIG_FILE = "Config.txt";
logic clk;
                   
dut
# (.CONFIG_FILE (CONFIG_FILE)) 
dut_inst
(.clk(clk));

endmodule
```

Compile with icarus:

```
> iverilog -g2012 tb2.sv
------
tb2.sv:12: error: Unable to bind variable `CONFIG_FILE' in `main'
1 error(s) during elaboration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got errors with `iverilog` on EDA Playground.  The error message was different from yours, which likely means the version of `iverilog` is different.

This compiles without errors on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/8722)

```
module dut #(parameter CONFIG_FILE="file.txt") 
(
input logic clk
);
endmodule

module main;
localparam CONFIG_FILE = "Config.txt";
logic clk;
                   
dut
# (.CONFIG_FILE (CONFIG_FILE)) 
dut_inst
(.clk(clk));

endmodule
```

That version does not like `string` being used with parameters, apparently.  However, in this case, it is not necessary to use the `string` keyword.

It also required a default value for the parameter.

`iverilog` doesn't support all SystemVerilog features (IEEE Std 1800-2017).